# Silverlight combobox null item height

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, combobox

I have following combobox:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmb2" ItemsSource="{Binding SignCollection, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Sign Collection is List and its first element is null. My problem is that when i run my application all items shown normally but first one(which is null) has really small height(it's still there and selectable). So, my question is how can i force it to have same height as everything else.

Comment: You really shouldn't include a null value in your collection... a better way to handle things is to have a `public bool IsNull { get; private set; }` -- It's a faux way to represent a null value.

Comment: I actually also have twoway binding for selecteditem to nullable property. I can write converter, but i'm lazy. Zortkun has my thanks for providing solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb2" ItemsSource="{Binding SignCollection, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
               <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
         </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

- 50: example fixed height

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..hope this will help you.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbType" SelectedIndex="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5,0,0" Width="250" Height="23" >
                    <ComboBoxItem>--Select Type--</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Errors</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Logs</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Thanks.[image]